# How to open a GPG encrypted file without having to choose the GPG recipient with the gnupg plugin?

Tags: variables, environment-variables

I want to edit a GPG encrypted file `file.asc` without having to split the window to enter the recipient.

The recipient can be set in the `vimrc`.

```
:let g:GPGDefaultRecipients='<key ID>'
```

**How would you suggest to parametrize/modify the gnupg plugin to automatically set the right recipient?**

Comment: @grochmal It's not uncommon to encrypt to yourself and others.  It's more common with mail, but also happens in other circumstances so I wouldn't say `you're probably doing it wrong`.

Comment: @jamessan - but, if you are encrypting for others, you wouldn't be able to decrypt it anyway (and therefore not able to edit), right?  That's how I understand pubkey cypto at least.  Or I'm simply missing that gnupg-vim uses symmetric enc for files?  Sorry for that if it is the case.  Yet, for symmeric enc Vim has blowfish built-in.

Comment: @grochmal You can specify multiple recipients with asymmetric encryption.  That's how it works for email.  If you couldn't encrypt it to yourself + the recipient, then you wouldn't be able to read it.  vim-gnupg also supports symmetric encryption.

Comment: @jamessan - god, yeah.  I completely forgot that trick (encrypt to someone and yourself, so you can edit as long a s you have your key and someone's pubkey).  I feel stupid now.  Removed the (quite bad) first comment.  Thanks for that.

Comment: @user123456 You shouldn't have to manually open the recipient dialog.  When you open a new file that matches the "encrypted file" pattern, it will automatically run the recipients dialog.  Just enter the recipients there and then close the window.

Answer (score 1):

I'd better create an "empty" GPG encrypted file with the proper recipient and open it.

```
echo ""  | gpg -a -e -r <GPG ID/mail> > doc.asc
vim doc.asc
```